# loop definition in columns cause application defined or object defined error

Tags: vba, loops, object

I want VBA compare cells(y, x) with cells(y, x-3). x should be from column 35 to column 2. However, if I define x as 'For x = 35 to 2 step -3, vba will have 'application -defined or object defined' error. If i define x as ' For x= 35 to 5, step -3' the code works fine, but it will skip calculation of column 2. How to solve the problem here? Here is the code.

```
Sub testing1()


Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer

For x = 35 To 5 Step -3
For y = 11 To 76 Step 1

If IsNumeric(Cells(y, x).Value) Then

If VBA.Abs(Cells(y, x).Value) < VBA.Abs(0.9 * Cells(y, x - 3).Value) Or _
  VBA.Abs(Cells(y, x).Value) > VBA.Abs(1.1 * Cells(y, x - 3)) Then

     Cells(y, x).Interior.ColorIndex = 22

ElseIf VBA.Abs(Cells(y, x).Value) < VBA.Abs(0.9 *   
     Workbooks("2014variance.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, x)) Or _
        VBA.Abs(Cells(y, x).Value) > VBA.Abs(1.1 * 
     Workbooks("2014variance.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, x)) Then

        Cells(y, x).Interior.ColorIndex = 42



End If
End If

Next y
Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When x = 2, x - 3 = -1. There is no column -1. This is why you get the error you do -- the `Excel Application` isn't able to return any cell when you use `Cells(y,x-3)` with x = 2.

If you want to treat the part involving `Cells(y,x-3))` as false in the case that `x=2` rather than throwing an error then you need another conditional to handle the case of `x=2` differently. Something like:

```
For x = 35 To 2 Step -3
    For y = 11 To 76 Step 1
        If IsNumeric(Cells(y, x).Value) Then
            If x > 2 Then
                If Abs(Cells(y, x).Value) < Abs(0.9 * Cells(y, x - 3).Value) Or _
                    Abs(Cells(y, x).Value) > Abs(1.1 * Cells(y, x - 3)) Then
                    Cells(y, x).Interior.ColorIndex = 22

                ElseIf Abs(Cells(y, x).Value) < Abs(0.9 * Workbooks("2014variance.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, x)) Or _
                        Abs(Cells(y, x).Value) > Abs(1.1 * Workbooks("2014variance.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, x)) Then
                    Cells(y, x).Interior.ColorIndex = 42
                End If
            Else 'x = 2 case
                If Abs(Cells(y, x).Value) < Abs(0.9 * Workbooks("2014variance.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, x)) Or _
                        Abs(Cells(y, x).Value) > Abs(1.1 * Workbooks("2014variance.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, x)) Then
                    Cells(y, x).Interior.ColorIndex = 42
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next y
Next x
```

There is probably some way to express this more elegantly, though VBA's lack of short-circuit evaluation makes it impossible to formulate conditionals where some of the sub-expressions are undefined, so this might be best.

I replaced `VBA.Abs()` by `Abs()` since I don't know of any reason to that you need to tell VBA how to find `Abs`.

Comment: I agree with what you said. I want Excel to compare column 2 in 2015.xlsx with column 2 in 2014.xlsx. My goals are to compare x with x-3 in 2015.xlsx, and then compare x in 2015 with 2014. Other columns work find but just column 2 is a trouble. Do you know how to fix the code?